# How to make C# connect only to an encrypted Access file

Tags: c#, oledb

The problem is that it connects to the encrypted file by password, but if you decrypt the Access file, it still connects

I did so, but anyway, if the file "File.accdb" is not encrypted, it connects
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\File.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database = True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=12345"

Comment: So, what is the question? To connect just for encrypted db file? Or to make db file not encrypted?

Comment: If the first one, you can check attribute by this code `bool isEncrypted = (System.IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.Encrypted) != 0;
`

Comment: To connect just for encrypted db file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Like I post in comments, you can use that code snippets.
Here is the idea.

```
string filePath = "File.accdb";

// Check if the file is encrypted
bool isEncrypted = (System.IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.Encrypted) != 0;

if (!isEncrypted)
{
    // The file is not encrypted; prevent the connection
    Console.WriteLine("The Access file is not encrypted. Connection denied.");
}
else
{
    // The file is encrypted; establish the connection
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=your-password";
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to the encrypted Access file.");
            // Perform your database operations here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to the database: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This checks the encryption on the Windows side. I need to check the Assess file with a password or not

Answer (score 0):

I did it so as not to miss the access file without passwords

```
private void checkData()
{
    string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\MyData.accdb";

    try
    {
        string connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={filePath};";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**